# Can I Configure SVN To Resolve My Conflict Better?

Tags: svn, merge-conflict-resolution

I use [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) as my external merge tool with SVN and very frequently it automatically merges all the conflicts that SVN fails on with no interaction from me.

Is there a setting to give SVN more context or something else that might help it resolve the conflicts as well as KDiff3?

Alternatively, is it possible to configure SVN to attempt the merge with the external tool before prompting me?

EDIT: The solution seems to be the diff3-cmd and getting KDiff3 to automatically save without prompting when all the conflicts are resolved. So an accepted answer will probably be a bat file for kdiff3 and some svn config.

Comment: [the manual states there is](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html#svn.advanced.externaldifftools.diff3), did you try to supply a `--diff3-cmd` ? You can also set your preference for it in `~/.subversion/config`.

Comment: Thanks. If you put this as an answer instead of a comment I could accept it. If you know how to make KDiff3 exit automatically and save changes on successful resolution too that would enhance the answer too.

Comment: I have kdiff3 here at work, I'll try some things here if I have time between actual work, and see if I can whip up a _complete_ answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subversion resolve all conflicts quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109723/subversion-resolve-all-conflicts-quickly)